# image inside a table <tr> after ng-repeat not rendered properly

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table which has dynamic trs been created by an ng-repeat just beneath that i have another tr which is supposed to contain an image.

```
<table>
<tr><th>Name<th>Age</th></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="obj in Data"><td>{{obj.name}}</td><td>{{obj.age}}</td></tr>
<tr><img src="http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading1.gif"/>/tr>
</table>
```

The issue is that the image is always displayed before the table .Its not rendered inside the table nor tr.

Can someone please shed some light on this.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rpsc8vz/1) demonstrating the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to wrap the image inside a `<td>` tag.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading1.gif"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Also, the closing `<tr>` tag in your code is broken. `/tr>`

You could also add a `colspan` attribute to the `<td>` tag and set it to 2, to maintain your table structure. (Because the ng-repeat produces two cells inside the column)

```
<td colspan="2">
    ...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krtecg5e/)

Comment: <td></td> was the one i had missed out.